# Filter Value in flutter mobile vision

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Please how can I filter numbers from flutter mobile vision using regex.

e.g `1578-7377-83974-5759`

Here is my function

```
  String datax() {
    RegExp regEx = RegExp(r'\d{1,6}-\d{1,6}-\d1,6}-\d{1,6}',
        caseSensitive: false, multiLine: false);
    String xc = "";
    if (regEx.hasMatch(_textsOcr[0].value)) {
      xc = _textsOcr[0].value;
    }
    return xc;
  }
```

But it's not working.

Please help.

Here is the link to the package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision_2

Comment: you mean add - after your evey 4 number like your example - **1578-7377-83974-5759**

Comment: Yes. I just want to filter out some certain number after scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it help to you :

Declare One empty **String** , and **TextEditingController** widget like below:

```
String cardNumber = '';

       Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      // call CardNumberFormatter class below
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        CardNumberFormatter(),
                      ],
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX',
                        labelText: 'Card Number',
                      ),
                      maxLength: 19,// change max length your need
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          cardNumber = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(cardNumber),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Declare one class for validation like below :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CardNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue previousValue,
    TextEditingValue nextValue,
  ) {
    var inputText = nextValue.text;

    if (nextValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return nextValue;
    }

    var bufferString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
      bufferString.write(inputText[i]);
      var nonZeroIndexValue = i + 1;
      // change below 4 value on your need like 1,2,3 etc
      if (nonZeroIndexValue % 4 == 0 && nonZeroIndexValue != inputText.length) {
        // change below '-' value on your need like ' ',/,_
        bufferString.write('-');
      }
    }

    var string = bufferString.toString();
    return nextValue.copyWith(
      text: string,
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: string.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your Screen look like-> [image]